# Difference between -- in `npm run` and `pnpm run`?

Tags: npm, pnpm

If I do:
`pnpm run typeorm migration:generate -- -d ./src/config/typeorm.ts ./src/migrations/`

I get an error that not enough arguments were passed to the script.

```
Not enough non-option arguments: got 0, need at least 1
```

When I run the same thing with nom like:
`npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -d ./src/config/typeorm.ts ./src/migrations/`

I don't get an error.

What's the difference in argument passing between these two commands?